# Table with partial line on the top

Tags: tables, multicolumn, hline

I would like to mimecry the following table in LateX:

[image]

I have tried the following code but I am having hard time to get the partial line on the top (the content is not important, only the top line to specify to 'Tukey comparisons'):

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccccccc} 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
\multicolumn{6}{c}{Tukey’s HSD comparisons}\\
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
group & n & Mean & SD & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 \\ 
\hline\\[-1.8ex] 
1998 & 256 & 79.71 & 13.40 &  & & \\ 
1999 & 307 & 82.34 & 13.30 & .005 & & \\ 
2001 & 292 & 92.23 & 6.57 & $<$.001 & $<$.001 & $<$.032 \\
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I would be grateful for some tips here.[image]

Comment: `\cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the heading to the last three columns: `&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Tukey’s HSD comparisons}` and either `\cline` or `\cmidrule` for the partial rule (the first has better spacing)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} ccccccc} 
\toprule
&&&&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Tukey’s HSD comparisons}\\
\cmidrule{5-7}
group & n & Mean & SD & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 \\ 
\midrule
1998 & 256 & 79.71 & 13.40 &  & & \\ 
1999 & 307 & 82.34 & 13.30 & .005 & & \\ 
2001 & 292 & 92.23 & 6.57 & $<$.001 & $<$.001 & $<$.032 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I would add also `\usepackage{caption}` for a better caption positioning, and `siunitx` for the numbers alignment.